# Xcode 9.2 + Fails Building : Invalid bitcode signature

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, build, phonegap

Good Morning!
Well I've been maintaining an ionic Cordova app but I'm having to upgrade it to the Iphone and I'm not getting it I've already searched a lot in various corners but I still can not solve my problem.

Log error
https://pastebin.com/f6c9N32p

Ionic V1 Info

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
Cordova Platforms : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.0
Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.1.0
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2
Node       : v8.9.3
npm        : 5.5.1
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Plugin List

> cordova-plugin-console 1.0.7 "Console"
>
> cordova-plugin-device 1.1.3 "Device"
>
> cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.9.1 "Facebook Connect"
>
> cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.6.0-dev "InAppBrowser"
>
> cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.0 "Splashscreen"
>
> cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.0 "StatusBar"
>
> cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.0 "Whitelist"
>
> ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
>
> phonegap-plugin-push 2.1.2 "PushPlugin"

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure it out yet?

Answer (score 2):

Setting the "Build Active Architecture Only" to 'Yes' resolved the same issue on my end.

Build Active Architecture Only is on Xcode -> Build Settings

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change value to "No" of **Enable Bitcode**

[XCode ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAJYx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is my solution, Go to the general properties, and uncheck the "Automatically manage signing" checkbox, and then check it again